# Why can't we use vector images for icons in Android?

Tags: android, icons, vector-graphics

By default, Android creates the mipmap directories for the icons. But, the support for Vector images is provided starting with *Android Support Library 23.2*. Vectors are recommended for small resolution images([less than 200dpx200dp recommendation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio)) and keeps the App size down.

So, why can't we use(or why is it not recommended) vector images for App icon instead by default?

Answer (score 0):

You can change default icon and use your own app icon. By creating vector icon.
Right click on resources and create a new vector image from there.